# how to make drag and drop tree structure of nested array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building a angular app. How do i create a draggable piramide of images. (see image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ijy.jpg

I'm using angular 7 with material design.

I already tried using:
* angular2-tree
* A combination of tree and drag and drop within material design but can't seem to get the desired piramide (frond-end) and a working back-end.

I use the following structure to create the tree

```
const TREE_DATA: Node[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: '1',
    prevId: 0,
    children: [
      {id: 2, name: '2', prevId: 1},
      {id: 3, name: '3', prevId: 1},
      {id: 4, name: '4', prevId: 1},
      {id: 5, name: '5', prevId: 1,
        children: [
          {id: 6, name: '6', prevId: 5,
            children: [
              {id: 7, name: '7', prevId: 6},
              {id: 8, name: '8', prevId: 6},
            ]
          },
          {id: 9, name: '9', prevId: 5,
            children: [
              {id: 10, name: '10', prevId: 9},
              {id: 11, name: '11', prevId: 9},
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want a piramide like structure with a drag and drop functionality. This so the pictures can be rearranged within the tree/piramide.

Comment: it will be easy if you go like folder structure

Comment: Angular Material provide drag n drop functionality. Please check documentation. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists

Comment: Yes i know @HassanSiddiqui only I cannot get a piramide like structure working.

Comment: can you share any working fiddle/stackblitz link? For more clarifications. Thanks